# elasticsearch Get aggregations in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How can I get the aggregations of a query in Java?

This is my query:

```
GET my_dataset/document/_search
     {
        "query": {
             "match": {
                 "docId": "1"
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "text": {
                "avg": {
                    "script": "doc['text'].values.size()" 
               }
            }
        }
     }
```

This is the output that I get

```
..
},
  "aggregations": {
    "text": {
      "value": 32
    }
  }
```

How can I get the value 32? I am trying the following with no success

```
response.getAggregations().getValue("text");
```

This is how I build the query in Java and get the response

```
  XContentBuilder aggregationBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
        aggregationBuilder.startObject()
               .startObject("query")
               .startObject("match")
               .field("docId", docID)
               .endObject()
               .endObject()
               .startObject("aggs")
               .startObject("text")
               .startObject("max")
               .field("script", "doc['text'].values.size()")
               .endObject()
               .endObject()
               .endObject()
               .endObject();

                SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("my_dataset").setTypes("document")
                                        .setSource(aggregationBuilder)
                                        .execute()
                                        .actionGet();
```

This is the response that I got while debugging
[image]

Comment: Can you show how you're building your query in Java? Can you try `response.getAggregations().get("text").get("value");`?

Comment: get() is not a valid method for the aggregation. get("value") gives that error before compiling.

Comment: Fair enough. If you set a breakpoint after the query has run, what do you see in the `response.getAggregations()` object?

Comment: Solved. It is response.getAggregations().get("text").getProperty("value")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked is

```
response.getAggregations().get("text").getProperty("value")
```

getProperty("value") has to be used instead of getValue().

Comment: can you please explain, why you propose this solution? the question is very nice formulated and it seems a bit trivial to post such a bare answer (i'm pretty sure it's the right answer, but let us know why and how it helps with the problem mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
response.getAggregations().get("text").getValue();
```

Comment: Which version of ES client are you using ?

Comment: It is the version 2.3.3

Comment: https://static.javadoc.io/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.3.3/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/Aggregations.html if you are using the 2.3.3 lib the get("text") must not complain , also change the last call to getProperty https://static.javadoc.io/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.3.3/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/Aggregation.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-

Comment: get("text") does not complain but doesnt give me the value. getProperty() does not compile, same as getValue();

Comment: OK, so what does get("text").getProperty("value") give you back ?

Comment: Throws an exception

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_metrics_aggregations.html

Example:

```
import org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.metrics.avg.Avg;
...
Avg avg = searchResponse.getAggregations().get("text");
double value = avg.getValue();
```

Tested with version 2.3.3.